# Error: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I just clone a project in rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3
I run `bundle install` successfully then once i run `rails s RAILS_ENV=development` i got this error:

```
ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

I tried all the solutions i found on stackoverflow and no one of them resolved my issue.
I am using postgresql 9.3 and ubuntu 14.04 LTS

here is my database.yml

```
  credentials: &config
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password25
  host: localhost

development:
  database: myproject_development
  <<: *config

test: &test
  database: myproject_test
  <<: *config

production:
  database: myproject_production
  <<: *config

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your database.yml, probably there's smth wrong there

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev Thanks I have updated my post adding the database.yml

Comment: well as i can see, your file has indentation problem in first line itself, also try running server with `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`

Comment: @RaviMariya this was my issue: the file isn't indented well. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies with your setup here.

```
credentials: &config
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password25
  host: localhost
```

Please change it to the following.

```
default: &config
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password25
  host: localhost
```

I wonder why used `credentials` instead of `default` in the first place. Hope it helps.

Comment: Pauldyal thanks for this answer but i still have the same error i guess changing credentials to default is not the solution for my issue